# php code to insert data into xml file

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to insert data into xml file.
For Ex:

```
<list>
    <activity>swimming</activity>
    <activity>running</activity>
</list>
```

In place of swimming i want to insert different data(ex:jogging)
How can i do that?

Comment: There is an `edit` button near bottom left corner of the question - use it to update your existing questions instead of posting a new one. Select your code and hit ctrl-k for formatting it. [more formatting tips](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: @Amarghosh Thanks for posting that link.  It will soon become my favorite link to post in comments, I'm certain.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting data in XML file with PHP DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194574/inserting-data-in-xml-file-with-php-dom)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php code to inset data into xml file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243619/php-code-to-inset-data-into-xml-file)

Answer (score 1):

Use a PHP XML library, such as http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php .  Unfortunately, when you're modifying an XML document with a simple interface, you often have to regenerate the document.  If you use a stream-based processor you may be able to avoid this.

Comment: I got simplexml for only reading..Actually i want to insert data into xml file. can u please send the code

Comment: @kavita123: You're asking me to spend my time writing code so that you don't have to?