# insert multiple data in xml with php dom

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

since i'm new to xml, i tried out [the code over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194574/inserting-data-in-xml-file-with-php-dom), to insert data into xml, which works. But I would like to insert multiple data into xml. how would i achieve that? for example:

```
<root>
<no>1</no>
<activity>swimming</activity>
<date>29/7/2010</date>
<others>
   <data1>data1</data1>
   <data2>data2</data2>
   <data3>data3</data3>
   so on..
</others>
<no>2</no>
<activity>sleeping</activity>
<date>29/7/2010</date>
<others>
   <data1>data1</data1>
   <data2>data2</data2>
   <data3>data3</data3>
   so on..
</others>
</root>
```

index.php:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('sample.xml', LIBXML_NOBLANKS);

    $activities = $xmldoc->firstChild->firstChild;
    if($activities != null){
            while($activities != null){
                            ?>
            <div id="xml">
                <span>
                <?php echo $activities->textContent ?> </span> <br />

            </div>
                        <?php
                        $activities = $activities->nextSibling;
            }
        }
 ?>

<body>
<form name="input" action="insert.php" method="post">
    Insert Activity:
    <input type="text" name="activity" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

insert.php:

```
<?php
    header("Location: index.php");

    $xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
    $xmldoc->load('sample.xml');
    $newAct = $_POST['activity'];

    $root = $xmldoc->firstChild;
    $newElement = $xmldoc->createElement('activity');
    $root->appendChild($newElement);
    $newText = $xmldoc->createTextNode($newAct);
    $newElement->appendChild($newText);
    $xmldoc->save('sample.xml');

?>
```

the above code inserts only one node. i would like to know how to insert multiple nodes and child nodes

Comment: What is your question or what is not working? Please add some more explanation.

Comment: the above code inserts only one node. i would like to know how to insert multiple nodes and child nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean *"how to insert multiple nodes at once in one method call"*, the answer is: it is impossible.

The approach with DOM is always the same: create a node and append it somewhere. One by one.

In your example above, you could leave out the TextNode creation and add the string content as the second argument to `createNode`. This would not use the automatic escaping and entity encoding though.

The only *method of mass creation* is [DOMDocumentFragment::appendXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocumentfragment.appendxml.php). This would take an arbitrary XML string for input. This is non-standard though.